# Late binding to a library with "extern" defined variables

Tags: c++, windows, extern, late-binding

I'm trying to late bind my program to a DLL.
I know how to import its methods but in one its header files, I have a definition like this:

```
EXTERN_C const IID SomeVariable;
```

How can I refer to this variable in my program without getting the "unresolved external symbol" error?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the late binding you are doing for functions ?

Comment: I know the function's signature, so I define a function pointer that matches it. Then I just call "GetProcAddress" with the DLL handle and the function's name. I assign the result to an instance of my function pointer and then I can use it as any other function.

Comment: Odds are very high that this variable is just not getting exported.  Use dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL to double-check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GetProcAddress to get the address of a function or variable.

Answer (score 1):

See [GetProcAddr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN.

```
const IID *idp = reinterpret_cast<const IID *>(GetProcAddr(hLibrary, "SomeVariable"));
```

Now you can refer to `SomeVariable` via the pointer - just like you can refer to the functions through their pointers.  You should, of course, check that the pointer is not null before you actually use it!